# How to apply changes from a major mode that I'm currently creating?

Tags: faces, major-mode, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a syntax highlighting mode for emacs, and wondering if there is a way to improve my workflow.

Currently I do this:

1. make edits to `mymode.el`
2. restart emacs
3. open `mymode.el`
4. eval buffer
5. open a file with the language to see the changes

Is there a way to quickly display the results of syntax mode changes, preferably without having to reload emacs?

[EDIT]

My font faces are defined using `(defface...` like so:

```
(defface my-lang-comment-face '((t (:inherit font-lock-comment-face)))
                              "comments" :group 'my-lang)
```

Should I be using `defconstant` or `setq` instead during development, then change it to `defface` when it's "done"?

Comment: Add a step 6. delete buffer containing file with the language using `C-x k`.  Then delete steps 2 and 3.  Your new loop should be steps 1, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: I tried this first - the result was no change to the syntax highlighting, even if I change things in `mymode.el`. The old syntax table is not replaced when I eval the mode. However I can do `M-x describe-variable RET my--syntax-table` and select `Forget`, confirm, then reload the mode and revisit the language file. But this is not better than restarting emacs. Really I just want to "reload" the entire mode, overwriting previous definitions with the new ones, but I can't figure out how to do that without restarting emacs.

Comment: I discovered that if I use `(defconst my-syntax-table ...)` rather than `(defvar my-syntax-table ...)` then I can actually `eval-buffer` and then reload the language buffer to see changes! I learned to use `defconst` if I want to be able to change the thing, versus `defvar` when it should never change. Great naming scheme there, thanks Emacs.